# How do I mark direct use of a superclasses method as an error while still allowing them to be used by subclasses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rollbar

It's worth noting that this question is primarily a theoretical one.  I suspect the real answer is 'just be careful not to do this!' and move on.  That said, it would be awesome if there were a way to do this, so that if this particular screw up happened -- as inevitably it will -- we can get a clear answer on when, how, who, why.  I'm trying to develop my professional understanding of software engineering, so if the answer is 'flawed data structure' or something like that, please do speak up.

I'm using inheritance to share data between different objects.  Most notably, an entire chain of objects is just a subclass of a single parent object.  And as a result, the mailers surrounding those objects are effectively identical.  There are some minor differences in the resulting text, but the setup code can be identical.

The issue is that while it can occasionally be valid to use the superclass of the data objects (the details differ, but a lot of the core logic is identical, hence the inheritance pattern here), it can never, and must never, be valid to use the root mailer object.  I've set it up so I never create the root data object; it's technically not valid to do so, but I don't think I can forbid that without forbidding use of that root model in general, which defeats the purpose of inheritance.

Some sample code to clarify my issue:

```
class RentalEndingWorker
  # stripped to psuedocode
  def perform
    rentals = Rental.rental_expiring_soon.where(warned:false)
    rental.deliver_warning_email
  end
end

class RentalMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def expiring_rental(rental)
    @rental = rental
    @client = rental.client
    @download = rental.show_download
    mail(to: @client.email, subject: 'Rental Expiring')
  end
end

class DigitalRentalMailer < RentalMailer
  def expiring_rental(rental)
    @download = rental.digital_download
    super
  end
end

class EquipmentRentalMailer < RentalMailer
  def expiring_rental(rental)
    @equipment = rental.equipment_variant
    super
  end
end
```

An Equipment Rental and a Digital Rental have totally different structures with regards to *what* has been rented.  In the relevant view, I'm going to want to use completely different relationship chains to describe them.  A digital download's 'name' is related to it's parents, DigitalProduct, DigitalVariant, and their associated categorizations.  An equipment's 'name' is build on it's relationship with Equipment & EquipmentVariant and their associated categorization objects.

What would be really nice -- and absolutely impossible as far as I'm aware -- would be:

```
class RentalMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def expiring_rental(rental)
    if called_directly_and_not_by_super
      Rollbar.error("Rental Mailer Used Directly")
    end
    @rental = rental
    @client = rental.client
    @download = rental.show_download
    mail(to: @client.email, subject: 'Rental Expiring')
  end
end
```

Comment: did you mean to make your Digital/Equipment mailers innherit from RentalMailer andn not ApplicationMailer?

Comment: i think you can just do `if self.class == RentalMailer`

Comment: _"I'm using inheritance to share data between different objects"_ – flaw :-)

Comment: Also, if that would be the case (the parent class issue max mentioned above), your `RentalMailer#expiring_rental` method currently strictly overwrites the instance variables on (super) call anyway, making it pointless to set them in the child-class methods.

Comment: In any case, the correct answer is probably: don't use `super` here but extract the common functionality into one or more separate methods which are then explicitly called with arguments instead of relying on global state set in a variety of places.

Comment: @maxpleaner woops, fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: @Stefan could you please explain?

I have three 'Rental' objects that are almost completely identical.  The only difference is which object is being rented -- in the case of the code above, whether it's a DigitalDownload or an Equipment.  How is that not an obvious case for subclassing?

Comment: I think the point Stefan is possibly making is that you are using inheritance only to share data between objects, there is no real obvious hierarchical structure, the RentalMailer seems to only be there to lump together some common things, and not modelling an Object Oriented hierarchical structure. In making it so RentalMailer can't be directly used, it is more like you are trying to achieve something close to an interface, with a bit of functionality. In which case composition over inheritance would work better I think. Extract shared bits out into a module to be set.

Comment: @JohnHayes-Reed that's a good point, I suppose.  I thought he was referring to the actual data objects, where I do in fact use the core Rental class when I don't care about which of the items I'm using.  In this case, yeah, RentalMailer is a mistake -- time to go do some composition instead.

Comment: May I answer via: https://youtu.be/9lv2lBq6x4A?t=30m50s (the whole talk is great – watch it!)

Comment: @Stefan I think I may need to watch and rewatch that a few times, because it seems to suggest that yes, this is a good place for subclassing -- at least, for the underlying data objects, if not the mailers.  Each of the three rental objects is, in fact, a specific type of a more generic 'rental' object.